# Script to update EC2 instances with new version of application remotely

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I want to write a script to update my ubuntu machines with new applications remotely. My machines are in private subnet under Elastic load balancer.

Comment: If your application is Elastic Beanstalk compatible, you can use Git and "aws.push" command to update applications. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-reference-branch-environment.html

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://www.ansible.com/home. The only thing it needs on a remote linux computer is ssh and python.